# Unable to find Image (Coding in Atom for Visual Novel Creation in Ren'py Visual Novel Engine)

Tags: compiler-errors, renpy

```
While loading <'Image' u'Volume1.png'>:
  File "game/script.rpy", line 7, in script
    "Welcome."
  File "renpy/common/000window.rpy", line 98, in _window_auto_callback
    _window_show()
  File "renpy/common/000window.rpy", line 60, in _window_show
    renpy.with_statement(trans)
IOError: Couldn't find file 'Volume1.png'.
```

I get this error when I run this code in Atom. I do have the image on file where it's supposed to be. I'm developing a visual novel in Ren'Py. The language is Python.

This is the code -

```
image Volume1 = "Volume1.png"

label start:

scene Volume1

"Welcome."

return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have Volume1.png in the images folder, it should work. Check that name of the image is indeed Volume1 and not volume1, as Ren'Py is pretty picky about upper and lower case.

Test that you can show the image: show Volume1. If the problem persist, rename the file to something else, as VolumeN may be a reserver word.